# align graphic and caption with text width using beside caption

Tags: graphics, captions, textwidth

I am trying to align my figure with the \captionbeside within the textwidth. The figure and the caption next to it should be each 0.5\textwidth and should not go beyond the textwidth in the margin.

Please let me know if there is something missing to understand the question!

(The code I have is adapted from The KOMA-Script-Guide by Markus Kohm: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf)

```
\documentclass[captions=centeredbeside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{captionbeside}{This is an example caption of a length comparable to my
caption length.This is an example caption comparable to my caption lenght. This is an examplecaption of a length comparable to my caption length.This is an example caption comparable to my caption length.}
[l][\linewidth][%
\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax
]*
\raisebox{%
\dimexpr\baselineskip-\totalheight\relax
}{% 
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{figure1}
 }%
\end{captionbeside}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove all the manual interventions, your caption and image will automatically be placed within the textwidth:

```
\documentclass[captions=centeredbeside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{captionbeside}{This is an example caption of a length comparable to my caption length.This is an example caption comparable to my caption lenght. This is an examplecaption of a length comparable to my caption length.This is an example caption comparable to my caption length.}
[l]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{figure1}
\end{captionbeside}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try that right in the beginning... Thank you so much!

Comment: @BeatrixKeweloh You're welcome!